# how to get a range of frames(for example frames 30 - 50) from a video file using opencv

Tags: python, python-2.7, opencv

currently my code gets all the frames in a video but i only need a few(about 20) from each video file.

```
import cv2 as cv
d = 1
count = 0
for i in range(5):
    s = '/home/mrrobot/Downloads/clipsnew/' + str(d) +'.mp4'
    vidcap = cv.VideoCapture(s)

    success,image = vidcap.read()

    success = True
    while success:
        vidcap.set(30,50)  #Does this even work?
        cv.imwrite("/home/mrrobot/Downloads/image2/frame%d.jpg" % count, image)     
        success,image = vidcap.read()
        print ('Read a new frame: ', success)
        count += 1
    d += 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

simply add condition that count should be less than 50 and skip first 30 frames OR set `CV_CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES` property to 30 and read 20 frames

```
import cv2 as cv
d = 1
for i in range(5):
    s = '/home/mrrobot/Downloads/clipsnew/' + str(d) +'.mp4'
    vidcap = cv.VideoCapture(s)

    success,image = vidcap.read()

    success = True
    count = 0
    while success and count < 50:
        if count >= 30:
            cv.imwrite("/home/mrrobot/Downloads/image2/frame%d.jpg" % count, image)
        success,image = vidcap.read()
        print ('Read a new frame: ', success)
        count += 1
    d += 1
```